# Why this validation gives me always required?

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js

probably I'm doing something wrong, I have been coding by instinct haha. Laravel validation seems super easy to implement but for some reason between my vuejs component to my php function I'm always getting "required".
I'm new with both Laravel and Vuejs, it seems to me that my php function is fine (for what I can see on the web) but probably I'm missing something on the comunication between laravel and vue. Can you tell me whats wrong?

```
public function createTag(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $data = request()->validate([
                'title' => 'required'
            ]);

            $tag = new Tag;
            $tag->title = $request->title;
            if($tag->save())
            {
                $tag->usercontracts()->attach($request->usercontractId);
            }

            return response()->success(__('success.showing', ['resource' => 'des Vertrags', 'resourceE' => 'tag']), $tag->id, 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->error(__('error.showing', ['resource' => 'des Vertrags', 'resourceE' => 'tag']), 400, $e);
        }
    }
```

```
<template>
  <div id="relative">
    <button @click.prevent="show = 1" v-if="show == 0">+tag</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="title" name="title" v-if="show == 1">
    <button @click="createTag" v-if="show == 1">add</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import TagService from "@/services/TagService";
export default {
  name: "add-tag-component",
  props: ['usercontractId'],
  data(){
    return {
      title:null,
      show:0
    };
  },
  methods:
  {
    async createTag()
    {
      const {body: {data}} = await TagService.createTag(this.title, this.usercontractId);
      this.$emit('addedTag', this.title, data);
      this.title = '';
      this.show = 0;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is TagService

```
export default {
    createTag(title, usercontractId, tagId) {
        return Vue.http.post(`contract/createTag/${title}/${usercontractId}`, tagId);
    }
}
```

I'm also getting this error. May be here is the answer?

Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "[object Object]"

found in

--->  at resources/assets/js/components/contract/listing/AddTagComponent.vue
 at resources/assets/js/components/contract/listing/ContractListingItemComponent.vue
 at resources/assets/js/components/contract/listing/ContractListingComponent.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **TagService**

You need to pass the `${title}` as payload not as uri.

```
export default {
    createTag(title, usercontractId, tagId) {
        return Vue.http.post(`contract/createTag/${title}/${usercontractId}`, tagId);
    }
}
```

to

```js
export default {
    createTag(title, usercontractId, tagId) {
        return Vue.http.post(`contract/createTag`, {
            tagId: tagId,
            title: title,
            usercontractId: usercontractId
        });
    }
}
```

Laravel validates the payload you pass.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I can go to sleep now haha. Ok, yes, clearly I have no idea what I'm doing with vuejs, it's gonna take time for me to get use to javascript. Thank you again.